# GTK app HeaderBar Error after conversion from C to C++ (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, g++, gtk, gtk3

I'm converting an application of mine from C to C++ (primarily to overcome some external hardware library issues). I've got the application now working on my local Gnome3 Ubuntu dev machine but it's no longer running on my Raspberry Pi, failing with GTK errors:

```
(Carputer:10150): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2:19: Theming engine 'adwaita' not found

(Carputer:10150): Gtk-WARNING **: /usr/src/packages/BUILD/gtk+3.0-3.14.5/./gtk/gtkcontainer.c:1174: child property `position' of container class `GtkHeaderBar' is not writable

(Carputer:10150): Gtk-WARNING **: /usr/src/packages/BUILD/gtk+3.0-3.14.5/./gtk/gtkcontainer.c:1174: child property `position' of container class `GtkHeaderBar' is not writable
```

Raspberry Pi is Debian Jessie running LXDE. Not sure if this is a GTK version issue given that it's only just started since i've changed the compiler (from GCC to G++).

Comment: Please show the code relevant to the error messages you see: what sets the `property` field of a GtkHeaderBar child?

Comment: I've removed all references to HeaderBar in my code - I imagine it's coming from the HeaderBar integration in Glade. So weird that's different compiler has it erroring only on the Raspberry Pi

Comment: Then can you paste the headerbar definition in the glade file? As well as the first few lines of the glade file?